# How to look for research opportunities in a different field?

Tags: phd, research-topic, changing-fields

I am a physics student doing a one-year taught master's program. Previously, I completed my Bachelor's degree with 2.5 years of research experience in subfield A of physics, with a few publications in A.

However, in my master's program, my coursework is mainly focused on field B instead. A and B are quite unrelated, so I am basically studying B as a complete beginner. Compared to my peers who have already done relevant research in B, I think it would be a disadvantage if I want to pursue B for my PhD. (My grade on the transcript also doesn't look very well.) However, I am still very interested in B, but I don't know how I can look for research opportunities in B without a strong background. Also, I am completing my program just in 2 months, so I don't think it would be easy for me to get in touch with a professor and conduct research in this field.

My question is what should I do if I still want to consider pursuing B in the future? I know it's possible for me to self-study to improve my background knowledge, but how can I look for research opportunities in B?

Comment: To clarify, by "research opportunities," you mean PhD supervision?

Comment: @Azor Ahai -him- Thanks for the comment! By that I mean either PhD supervision or some informal research opportunities (such as research assistant) which help me learn deeper into B and then decide if B is the right field for me.

Comment: What is stopping you from applying for research assistant jobs?

Comment: @Azor Ahai -him- Because I am completing my program very soon, and my course would be very intense in the remaining time. I actually want to apply for research assistant or ask the postdocs at the department if they are willing to supervise me on some project after I complete the program, but I don't know if that's possible because at that time I will not be an enrolled student at my university.

Comment: So is your question looking for the magic formula to get a job/grad school in B, or are you literally asking how to identify open positions?

Answer (score 2):

You have provided quite a list of your disadvantages. But then you also have your advantage, a few publications in A, as you said. Not many people have publications when they are applying for PhD studies. The fact that these are in a different subfield is less important at this point. More relevant is that you know how to give shape to things and to turn your research into publishable papers. So, in your applications, make an emphasis on your research experience and on your publication record.

Also, over the remaining 2 month, why wouldn't you get in touch with some professor in area B and start some research? Getting back to my previous point, simply the fact that you have publications will make you look good in the eyes of your potential future adviser.

Comment: Thanks very much!!

Comment: @IGY Good luck with your studies and your PhD applications!